# R: From single columns to columns of X classes

Tags: r

I have a list similar to this one:

```
 yellow, green, blue, yellow,...
```

with 30 different levels. However, not level appears on the list.

And I would like to create a data frame like this:

```
yellow   green   blue   orange
 1         0       0      0
 0         1       0      0
 0         0       1      0
 1         0       0      0
```

Note there is an column named orange, even though the color does not appears on the list.

I tried already using dcast, melt and other functions from the reshape2 package.
Also, Im sure there should be an answer to this question, however I could not find it (probably I wasn't using the best keywords in Google).

Thanks

EDIT: Changed the shape of the data and the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `table` should do this in base R:

```
table(rownames(mydf), mydf$RESULT)
##    
##     blue green yellow
##   1    0     0      1
##   2    0     1      0
##   3    1     0      0
##   4    0     0      1
```

Other alternatives:

```
model.matrix(~RESULT + 0, mydf)
##   RESULTblue RESULTgreen RESULTyellow
## 1          0           0            1
## 2          0           1            0
## 3          1           0            0
## 4          0           0            1
## attr(,"assign")
## [1] 1 1 1
## attr(,"contrasts")
## attr(,"contrasts")$RESULT
## [1] "contr.treatment"
##
```

or

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, rownames(mydf) + RESULT ~ RESULT, fun.aggregate = length, 
    value.var = "RESULT")
##   rownames(mydf) RESULT blue green yellow
## 1              1 yellow    0     0      1
## 2              2  green    0     1      0
## 3              3   blue    1     0      0
## 4              4 yellow    0     0      1
```

---

For a simple vector, just try:

```
table(1:length(yourVec), yourVec)
```

or

```
model.matrix(~ vec + 0)
```

---

Use the `levels` argument in `factor` to modify the vector *before* using either of these approaches to make sure that you capture any values that may not be in the set but which you want in the output (example "orange").

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm getting this error "all arguments must have the same length". Maybe I explained my issue in a wrong way. What I currently have is a single vector (green, blue, blue, ...and so on), however it is made of 39 different levels and not all of them appears in the vector (it has around 200K elements).

Comment: @user3276768, then use the `table` approach, but change it to something like `table(1:length(yourVec), yourVec)`.

Comment: @user3276768, also look at the `factor` function.